# Ways to Redirect URLs

Tags: url-redirection

I'm looking for some interesting ways to redirect URLs. For example, `http://example.com:@example.org` will redirect to example.org. Are there any other ways to redirect/spoof URLs in a browser like that?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Take a read of the [RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt) for URLs - it covers all the options including the one you mentioned.

Comment: Thank you for that. I've used username:password@website, but I never really put 2 and 2 together to realize that was what I was using, but it didn't really go over anything else except other protocols like ftp, gopher, file, etc. unless I missed it. Thank you again.

Comment: That's because these kind of exploits are (obviously) client-based. If you can't click on a URL (which pretty much limits your choice of targets to browsers) you can't fake it out with a weird URI.